# has_many through polymorphic with custom type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 applications one that serves as an API and has read only access and one that is the primary application. In the primary app, I have a has many through polymorphic relationship. The models in the main app look like so, and they work great:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_associations
  has_many :posts, through: :category_associations
  has_many :pages, through: :category_associations
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_associations, as: :associated
  has_many :categories, as: associated, through: :category_associations, source: :post
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_associations, as: :associated
  has_many :categories, as: associated, through: :category_associations, source: :post
end

class CategoryAssociation
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :associated, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now for the second app I will need to access the same tables but my class names will be different, this effects the type field that I cannot seem to override even with source_type.:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_associations
  has_many :articles, through: :category_associations
  has_many :static_contents, through: :category_associations
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'posts'

  has_many :category_associations, as: :associated
  has_many :categories, as: associated, through: :category_associations, source: :article, source_type: 'Post'
end

class StaticContent < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'pages'

  has_many :category_associations, as: :associated
  has_many :categories, as: associated, through: :category_associations, source: :static_content, source_type: 'Page'
end

class CategoryAssociation
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :associated, polymorphic: true
end
```

I get the following Error:

```
=> Posts.first.categories

# ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPointlessSourceTypeError: Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Post#categories' with a :source_type option if the 'CategoryAssociation#category' is not polymorphic. Try removing :source_type on your association.
```

It also seems that when I grab the posts from the category

Comment: try swap associations: **has_many category_associations** to **has_many categories**. others leave. i thinks that in "major" association which is **has_many :category_association** must have information about polymorphic model CategoryAssociation. has_many categories is sended to Category model which isn't polymorphic. So source_type with source is not necessary and gives you error.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried putting `polymorphic:true` to the category `belongs_to`? It seems that's the direction pointed by the error message points, though I'm not sure

```
class CategoryAssociation
  belongs_to :category, polymorphic: true
  ...
end
```